# Making a post in Web Api 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I am making an web api in Asp.Net MVC5 with web api2. I made a post Like this:

```
public class SmsClientsController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(Client client)
    {
        //Add Client to database
    }
}
```

the Model Client is like this:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }
}
```

and I called this post method on a button click, simply from javascript in client side like this:

```
function SendSms() {
    var studentData = {
        "Username": "Anjin",
        "Password": "Pradhan",
        "Role": "1"
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.0.102/ProductsApp/api/SmsClients",
        data: JSON.stringify(studentData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(jqXHR);
            alert("success..." + data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

But on response it just alerts a blank alert box. And when i checked the console through fire bug there was an error:

```
"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://192.168.0.102/ProductsApp/api/SmsClients"
```

Why is so happening?? Is this `Post` method invalid. Please help me to correct this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Changing the ip address (192.168.0.102) with `localhost` worked for me in my local server

Answer (score 3):

**WITHIN THE SAME PROJECTS (SAME DOMAIN)**

```
url: "http://192.168.0.102/ProductsApp/api/SmsClients",
```

If both WebAPI and MVC Pages are in the same project, I mean in same domain, then url should be as shown below -

```
url: "/api/values",
```

**IN DIFFERENT PROJECTS (DOMAINS)**

If they are in different projects, then you need to enable cors. To enable cors, first get the following nuget.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Then enable cors in WebApiConfig.cs -

```
config.EnableCors();
```

Then in the controller action you can place this attribute. Make sure you allow only proper origins instead of *

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
```

And now from other project, you can make a request in the following way -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function SendSms() {
        var studentData = {
            "Username": "Anjin",
            "Password": "Pradhan",
            "Role": "1"
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:23133/api/values",
            data: JSON.stringify(studentData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                alert("success..." + data);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" onclick="SendSms()" value="Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your configuration, but by default a web page cannot make calls to services (APIs) on a domain other than the one where the page came from. You most likely just have to implement CORS support.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx